# About histogram and shape of distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, histogram

Suppose that it was found in a company that the distribution of reviews among reviewers is highly skewed so that a small number of reviewers do most of the reviews while a larger number of reviewers do very few reviews. The distribution looks like an inverted yield curve. If the editors take 200 samples, each having 30 reviewers and if we plotted the histogram of the reviews, how the distribution will tend to look like? Is it like normal curve or it will look similar to the original distribution?

Comment: Are you asking (1) what the 200 histograms of 30 reviewers each will look like, or (2) what a single histogram of 200*30=6000 reviewers (with possible duplicates) will look like, or about (3) a histogram of 200 *averages*, each one computed from 30 reviewers?

Comment: I'm asking about one histogram. I think number (2) is the best option. 
All I want is to compare the shape of the distribution to the shape of the histogram

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume the underlying population of reviewers is large compared to the sample sizes, so duplicates will happen rarely in our sampling and not be a problem.

Then if we draw 200 samples of size 30 each and just lump them all together, we have 6000 data points (some of them possibly duplicates, but per the assumption, this will not have a major impact). For most "normal" distributions, this will likely be enough so the sample looks reasonably similar to the original distribution.

The easiest way to get an intuition for this kind of question is to simulate. For example, here is a population that looks like your description:

[image: population]

And here are 12 histograms of samples of size 6000, drawn with replacement:

[image: samples]

In exactly the same way, you can draw a couple of samples from the dataset you have and see visually whether the histograms (or other plots) of the sampled data look similar to the histogram of the full dataset. Do this multiple times so you don't run into one single bad example by mischance.

Of course, this may break down at the extremes. For instance, incomes have a highly skewed distribution, and if you draw a sample of 6000 individuals (or households) from the US, you will be highly unlikely to have randomly drawn someone from the top 0.1%.

R code for the plots:

```
set.seed(1)
population <- rnbinom(1e6,mu=1,size=1)+1
summary(population)
breaks <- seq(0.5,max(population)+0.5)
hist(population,breaks=breaks,main="Population",xlab="")

n_sample <- 200*30
opar <- par(mfrow=c(4,3),mai=c(.3,.5,.1,.1),las=1)
    for ( ii in 1:12 ) hist(sample(population,n_sample,replace=TRUE),breaks=breaks,xlab="",ylab="",main="")
par(opar)
```